# How to prevent premature opening of the 'Development' submenu when hovering over the 'Service' tab in a nested menu using React and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, tailwind-css

I am currently working on implementing a **nested menu using React and Tailwind CSS**. However, I've encountered a challenge: when hovering over the "Service" tab in the navbar, a submenu appears, but the complication arises as the "Development" tab is ***prematurely open***. The desired structure is as follows:

```
Services ->
          - Dummy tab 1 
          - Dummy tab 2
          - Development ->
                          - Dummy tab 3
                          - Dummy tab 4
```

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue and ensure a smooth user experience when interacting with the nested menu.

I've been working on this thus far.

```
export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex justify-evenly items-center p-4 font-medium">
        <img src="https://acrologix.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/acrologix-logo-header-01.png" alt="logo" className="h-[11vh] mr-40"></img>
        <div className="mr-20">
          <ul className="flex justify-center items-center gap-8">
            <li className="hover:text-blue-600"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li className="hover:text-blue-600"><a href="/">About</a></li>
            <li className="hover:text-blue-600"><a href="/">Our Clients</a></li>

            <div className="group relative inline-block">
              <div id="dropdownBtn" className="group-hover:text-blue-500 transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-black text-base border-none">Services</div>
              <div className="hidden absolute bg-white w-[380px] shadow-md z-10 group-hover:block transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-[13px] p-3 mt-1 rounded-md">

                {/* Existing menu items */}
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">Payment Gateway Integrations</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">Designing</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">Software Testing/QA</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">IT Infrastructure Development</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">Managed Services & Resource Outsourcing</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">Offshore Team Setup</a>

                {/* Development tab with submenu */}
                <div className='group relative inline-block'>
                  <div id='devtab' className='group-hover:text-blue-500 transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-black border-none text-base'>Dev</div>
                  <div className='hidden absolute bg-white w-[250px] shadow-md z-10 group-hover:block transition duration-300 ease-in-out'>
                    <a href='/'>dev</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>



            <div className="group relative inline-block">
              <div className="group-hover:text-blue-500 transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-black text-base border-none">Products</div>
              <div className="hidden absolute bg-white w-[350px] shadow-md z-10 group-hover:block transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-[13px] p-3 font-medium mt-1 rounded-md">
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">CampusInBox</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">PeopleInBox</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">FoodMart Grocery</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">FoodMart Resturant</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">TeckCure</a>
                <a href="/" className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm">ERP</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <li className="hover:text-blue-600"><a href="/">Contact</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state to conditionally render your menu and sub items on click/hover. Below is the code for your reference:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Navbar() {
    const [openSubMenuDev, setOpenSubMenuDev] = useState(false)
    const [openSubMenuProduct, setOpenSubMenuProduct] = useState(false)
    const [openSubMenuService, setOpenSubMenuService] = useState(false)

const handleClickDev = () => {
    setOpenSubMenuDev(!openSubMenuDev)
}

const handleClickProduct = () => {
    setOpenSubMenuProduct(!openSubMenuProduct)
}

const handleClickService = () => {
    setOpenSubMenuService(!openSubMenuService)
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="flex justify-evenly items-center p-4 font-medium">
            {/* <img src="https://acrologix.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/acrologix-logo-header-01.png" alt="logo" className="h-[11vh] mr-40"></img> */}
            <div className="mr-20">
                <ul className="flex justify-center items-center gap-8">
                    <li className="hover:text-blue-600">
                        <a href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="hover:text-blue-600">
                        <a href="/">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="hover:text-blue-600">
                        <a href="/">Our Clients</a>
                    </li>

                    <div className="group relative inline-block">
                        <div
                            id="dropdownBtn"
                            className="group-hover:text-blue-500 transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-black text-base border-none"
                            onClick={handleClickService}
                        >
                            Services
                        </div>
                        {openSubMenuService && <div className="hidden absolute bg-white w-[380px] shadow-md z-10 group-hover:block transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-[13px] p-3 mt-1 rounded-md">
                            {/* Existing menu items */}
                            <a
                                href="/"
                                className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                            >
                                Payment Gateway Integrations
                            </a>
                            <a
                                href="/"
                                className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                            >
                                Designing
                            </a>
                            <a
                                href="/"
                                className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                            >
                                Software Testing/QA
                            </a>
                            <a
                                href="/"
                                className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                            >
                                IT Infrastructure Development
                            </a>
                            <a
                                href="/"
                                className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                            >
                                Managed Services & Resource Outsourcing
                            </a>
                            <a
                                href="/"
                                className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                            >
                                Offshore Team Setup
                            </a>

                            {/* Development tab with submenu */}
                            <div className="group relative inline-block">
                                <div
                                    id="devtab"
                                    className="group-hover:text-blue-500 transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-black border-none text-base"
                                    onClick={handleClickDev}
                                >
                                    Dev
                                </div>
                                {openSubMenuDev && (
                                    <div className="hidden absolute bg-white w-[250px] shadow-md z-10 group-hover:block transition duration-300 ease-in-out">
                                        <a href="/">dev</a>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>}
                    </div>

                    <div className="group relative inline-block">
                        <div
                            className="group-hover:text-blue-500 transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-black text-base border-none"
                            onClick={handleClickProduct}
                        >
                            Products
                        </div>
                        {openSubMenuProduct && (
                            <div className="hidden absolute bg-white w-[350px] shadow-md z-10 group-hover:block transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-[13px] p-3 font-medium mt-1 rounded-md">
                                <a
                                    href="/"
                                    className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                                >
                                    CampusInBox
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    href="/"
                                    className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                                >
                                    PeopleInBox
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    href="/"
                                    className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                                >
                                    FoodMart Grocery
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    href="/"
                                    className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                                >
                                    FoodMart Resturant
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    href="/"
                                    className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                                >
                                    TeckCure
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    href="/"
                                    className="hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-blue-600 block px-4 py-3 text-black no-underline rounded-sm"
                                >
                                    ERP
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>

                    <li className="hover:text-blue-600">
                        <a href="/">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)
```

}